# PHP Codesniffer phpcs: ERROR: the squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf.dist coding standard is not installed in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, drupal-8, phpcodesniffer

I have a Drupal 8 installation where I want to use the `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` with PhpStorm.

I installed phpcs with Composer by following this documentation from Drupal itself https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/code-review-module/installing-coder-sniffer#s-composer-installer-plugin. I installed it with this command `composer global require drupal/coder dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer` which also installs `squizlabs/php_codesniffer`. At this point everything is working and phpcs is installed in my users `.composer` folder.

When I execute `phpcs --config-show` I get this output:
(version 3.6.1)

```
Using config file: /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf

installed_paths: /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer,/Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis
```

Looks fine in my opinion.

#### PhpStorm version 2021.2.2

Next step was setting up CodeSniffer in PhpStorm which I did like this:

[image: PHP_CodeSniffer settings in PhpStorm]

CodeSniffer was validated and seems to be OK. PhpStorm as well recognized the Drupal coding standard as you see here:

[image: Quality Tools PHP_CodeSniffer validation]

When I save all the settings and open a File I get this error message in the PhpStorm Event Log:

```
11:51   PHP_CodeSniffer
        phpcs: ERROR: the "/Users/myusername/Sites/projects/features/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.conf.dist" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are PEAR, Zend, PSR2, MySource, Squiz, PSR1, PSR12, Drupal, DrupalPractice and VariableAnalysis
        Open PHPCodeSniffer Inspection Settings
```

I have absolutely no idea why it needs to check the projects php_codesniffer and why this coding standard needs to be installed. Does somebody have an idea why this could be happening? I tried clearing PhpStorm Cache but that didn't help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check these tickets (comments) -- they seem related to your issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42964 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43028 P.S. Try installing PHP_CS as a project-specific dependency and not global one -- any better?

Comment: Hi @LazyOne. First of all sorry about the formatting, this was my first ever question here on stackoverflow. Thank you for your comment and the fast reply. I will look into those two issues and let you know if it helped. In my drupal installation I have phpcs installed and also tried setting the projects phpcs in Phpstorm but sadly the error still appears.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne I had a looks at those issues and don't really get what I need to do. I did this `phpcs --config-set installed_paths /path/to/standard` already but this didn't resolve my error message. I also changed the path to the phpcs executable to project specific path but this also didn't resolve the error message. I fixed it now by deleting the project and setting it up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself. For those who still need a solution I need to disappoint you. I just deleted my project and installed it again. After that the error doesn't appear anymore. This proves that phpcs or Drupal isn't the issue. It was my project setup.